# Module 'KissXML' not found - When using library react-native-xmpp in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, xmppframework

I am using [react-native-xmpp](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-xmpp) library for XMPP chat. the library works fine in android . But when I try to build on iOS ,I got an error 'Module 'KissXML' not found' in XMPPFramework library.

I followed the exact steps . But It doesn't build on xcode. I also tried

```
pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.7.0' pod 'KissXML', :git => "https://github.com/aksonov/KissXML.git", :branch => '5.1.4'
```

But pod didn't install these dependancy . Please help me

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add

```
pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.7.0'
```

only in the pod file . update the pod file and call pod install or pod update. KissXML library will be added as part of the XMPP framework

Comment: No luck. in NSXMLElement+XEP_0059.h file . it shows an error Module 'KissXML' not found